# Need help making a numbers list from array of objects

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, list, object

I'm having trouble making a numbered list of from array of objects.
Below is my code containing the objects. Add necessary TS code to show these atom names and their weights in a numbered list to using ol and li. Each row in the the list should show the atom name and its weight in the following format:

1. xxxxx (weight: xxxxx)
2. xxxxxxxxx (weight: xxxxxx)

```
export interface Atom {
  name: string;
  weight: number;
}

export const atomNames: string[] = [
  "Aluminum",
  "Barium",
  "Carbon",
  "Dubnium",
  "Erbium",
  "Fluor",
  "Gallium",
  "Hydrogen",
  "Helium",
  "Iron",
  "Krypton",
  "Lithium",
  "Magnesium",
  "Nitrogen",
  "Oxygen",
  "Palladium",
  "Radon",
  "Silicon",
  "Titanium",
  "Uranium",
  "Vanadium",
  "Xenon",
  "Zinc",
];

export const atomObjects: Atom[] = [
  { name: "Aluminum", weight: 26.982 },
  { name: "Barium", weight: 137.33 },
  { name: "Carbon", weight: 12.011 },
  { name: "Dubnium", weight: 268 },
  { name: "Erbium", weight: 167.26 },
  { name: "Fluor", weight: 18.988 },
  { name: "Gallium", weight: 69.723 },
  { name: "Hydrogen", weight: 1.008 },
  { name: "Helium", weight: 4.0026 },
  { name: "Iron", weight: 55.845 },
  { name: "Krypton", weight: 83.798 },
  { name: "Lithium", weight: 6.94 },
  { name: "Magnesium", weight: 24.305 },
  { name: "Nitrogen", weight: 14.007 },
  { name: "Oxygen", weight: 15.999 },
  { name: "Palladium", weight: 106.42 },
  { name: "Radon", weight: 222 },
  { name: "Silicon", weight: 28.085 },
  { name: "Titanium", weight: 47.867 },
  { name: "Uranium", weight: 238.03 },
  { name: "Vanadium", weight: 50.942 },
  { name: "Xenon", weight: 131.29 },
  { name: "Zinc", weight: 65.38 },
];
```

Here is my other javascript file

```
  // Find the placeholder node in the HTML document
const div2 = document.getElementById("part2");

// Create a new H2 and its text
const h2: HTMLHeadingElement = document.createElement("h2");
const h2text: Text = document.createTextNode("Part 2");
h2.appendChild(h2text);
div1?.appendChild(h2);

// create list from array object
const ol1 = document.createElement("ol");
let li1;

let result = atomObjects.map(({name,weight}) => ([name,weight]));
for (let j = 0; j < result.length;j++){
    li1 = document.createElement("li");
      li1.innerText = result[i];
    ol.appendChild(li1);
  }
  div1?.appendChild(ol1);
```

### HTML CODE

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="./part0.ts" defer> </script>
    <script src="./nunezjo.ts" defer> </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/mocha/mocha.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="mocha"></div>
    <div id="part0" class="result"></div>
    <div id="part1" class="result"></div>
    <div id="part2" class="result"></div>
    <div id="part3" class="result"></div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/chai/chai.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/chai-dom/chai-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/mocha/mocha.js"></script>
    <script class="mocha-init">
      mocha.setup("bdd");
      mocha.checkLeaks();
    </script>
    <script src="./mocha-checker.ts"></script>
    <script class="mocha-exec">
      mocha.run();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you just want to show your data in `HTML` page, you can do something like this

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div>ATOMS</div>
    <div id="atoms"></div>
    <script>
      const atomObjects = [
          { name: "Aluminum", weight: 26.982 },
          { name: "Barium", weight: 137.33 },
          { name: "Carbon", weight: 12.011 },
          { name: "Dubnium", weight: 268 },
          { name: "Erbium", weight: 167.26 },
          { name: "Fluor", weight: 18.988 },
          { name: "Gallium", weight: 69.723 },
          { name: "Hydrogen", weight: 1.008 },
          { name: "Helium", weight: 4.0026 },
          { name: "Iron", weight: 55.845 },
          { name: "Krypton", weight: 83.798 },
          { name: "Lithium", weight: 6.94 },
          { name: "Magnesium", weight: 24.305 },
          { name: "Nitrogen", weight: 14.007 },
          { name: "Oxygen", weight: 15.999 },
          { name: "Palladium", weight: 106.42 },
          { name: "Radon", weight: 222 },
          { name: "Silicon", weight: 28.085 },
          { name: "Titanium", weight: 47.867 },
          { name: "Uranium", weight: 238.03 },
          { name: "Vanadium", weight: 50.942 },
          { name: "Xenon", weight: 131.29 },
          { name: "Zinc", weight: 65.38 },
        ];
        
        const container = document.getElementById("atoms");
        atomObjects.forEach((item, index) => {
            const row = document.createElement('div');
            row.innerHTML = `${index+1}. ${item.name} (Weight: ${item.weight})`;
            container.appendChild(row);
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you want to use `<ol><li>....`, you can do that too, and remove the manual numbering.

```
<ol id="atoms"></ol>
.
.
.
atomObjects.forEach((item) => {
    const row = document.createElement('li');
    row.innerHTML = `${item.name} (Weight: ${item.weight})`;
    container.appendChild(row);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of front-end side numbering in your code is fine

e.g.

```
<ol>
   <li>{atomObject}</li>
</ol>
```

This will display as

```
1. Atom (weight)
```

Unless you want to store the index number in the actual object, then you'd have to add another attribute to the Atom class. Maybe clarify on why the indexing is important? Do you use it to reference? Or is it just for display?

Comment: Well only reason why I wanted to use indexing was to loop through the object array to display every name and weight, without having to do    <li>{atomObject}</li> for each name

Comment: Then my best advice is to then probably add an id property to each object. Otherwise you'll anyways have to end up doing some sort of iteration of a for loop by adding a number using the index of the array if that makes sense :) @JosueNunez